# Unit testing a controller method that is called via a custom route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

How do I unit test a controller method that is called via a custom route?

The relevant route is:

```
/auth/:provider/callback(.:format) {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"create"}
```

On the spec for the `SessionsController` I can't just use `get :create` since that route doesn't exist. If I also use `get /auth/facebook/callback/` it'll tell me that `No route matches {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"/auth/facebook/callback"}`.

It also seems like I can't just use `controller.create` since `#create` accesses some keys from the `request` hash and it also redirects to another path, even if I set request.env['something'] in the spec file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A functional test should test the function of each action
(given a set of parameters)

Crucially, you should keep your functional tests decoupled from your routes.
(else what's the point in the routing abstraction anyway)

In test::unit a functional test looks something like this

```
test "#{action_name} - does something" do
  #{http_verb} :#{action_name}, :params => {:their => "values"}
  assert_response :#{expected_response}
end
```

Note, we don't mention routing anywhere.

So a real example for your create

```
test "create - creates a session" do
  get :create, :provider => "your provider"
  assert_response :success
end
```

Rails will choke if it can't match a route to this request.

If this doesn't work I suggest you check two things

1. "get" is the correct http verb
2. there are no other required parameters in your route (I can see :provider is one)

If I'm doing anything wacky with routing,
I normally add a separate test.

```
test "create - routing" do
  assert_recognizes({
    :controller => "sessions",
    :action => "create",
    :provider => "yourProvider"
    }, "/auth/yourProvider/callback")
end
```

As long as this matches up with your action test
all should be well.

Comment: `get :create, :provider => 'provider name'` did the trick. Thank you!